# Merge count values in different columns in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the code and result, I need to show only one row...
any suggesions Thanks.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you mean one row? can you show your expected output?

Comment: Um... It's not actually possible for you to get a result set like that, with the query you posted, unless those college/department combinations are not the same (e.g. there's small differences in spellings or something we can't see from the screenshot). So either you've posted a query you're not actually using to get that result or there are typos.

Comment: Please provide your existing table schema and some sample data, as well as the desired results.

Comment: I added a desired output.  I am counting courses for each department on each month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `SUM` like this

```
SELECT  college,
        department,
        COUNT(department) as departmentCount,
        SUM(CASE when datepart(month,[date]) = 1 then 1 else 0 END) as [January],
        SUM(CASE when datepart(month,[date]) = 2 then 1 else 0 END) as [February]
From rpt_school
GROUP BY college,department
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question appears to have some errors, but I think you want to collapse the data so you have only one row per College and Department.  If so, you could use `max()` as in:

```
select
   College
  ,Department
  ,max(January) as January
  ,max(February) as February
  ,max(March) as March
from your_query_in_question     -- put your existing query here
group by
   College
  ,Department
```

Comment: How do I add the January value to the first selection, the first column January and February appears with red under line.... I tried similar code in Toad worked but sql server is new for me.